# What is the bandwidth of a type 1 or higher system?

Tags: control-system, gain

Since bandwidth is defined as the frequency at which the gain drops below -3dB compared to the low-frequency gain, how can i determine the bandwidth of a type 1 system where low-frequency gain is infinite?

Comment: Bandwidth is therefore zero.

Comment: What do you get when multiplying "infinite" with 0.7071?

Comment: You could try the question 'what's the frequency at which gain=your specification?'. *Bandwidth* is **not** defined as the frequency at which the gain drops below -3dB. The *3dB bandwidth* is defined as that. *Bandwidth* is defined however you want to define the particular type you have in mind.

Comment: There is no such thing as **infinite** gain. It is always finite.

Comment: A pure integrator is not strictly a low pass system, nor a mid pass, nor even a high pass. For a system that include pure integrators (type 1 or above) in the transfer function, it would be more useful the definition of crossover frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The question, which pertains to a physical system characteristic, is nonsensical for a pure integrator, which is an abstraction. In reality the integrator will have a finite timeconstant making the transfer function essentially $$G/(1+Ts),$$ and so the 3 dB bandwidth will be the frequency at which the OL gain G decreases by 3 dB. This is obviously invariant of the actual value of G so one might as well normalize it to 1 and find

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(T\omega)^2}} \approx 0.5012,$$

or (presuming I've not made an arithmetical error)

$$ \omega_{bw} \approx \frac{1.726}{T}.$$